# What is the use of undo manager? How to use it?

Tags: iphone, undo, undo-redo, nsundomanager, redo

What is the need of undo manager in iphone? I never see such buttons in sample programs. I know the meaning and the use of undo & redo. But my question here is, For which purpose, i need it? How to use it in my application? Also suggest a good example code link if you know...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Undo is used in many apps, including most or all of the Apple built-in ones wherever text editing occurs. Type or change some text in Mail or Safari and then shake your phone; you'll see an AlertView pop up asking you if you'd like to undo your text change.

There's a pretty good tutorial here:

**[Mobile Orchard: Shake To Undo/Redo, NSUndoManager](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-1-shake-to-undoredo-nsundomanager/)**

Comment: Yes, follow that link to the article on Mobile Orchard: it explains it and has example code.